# SQL server memory Investigation

Tags: sql-server, memory-management

I am investigating SQL server 2012 memory usage. I ran the below query

```
SELECT c.counter_name, c.cntr_value / 1000 AS 'Memory (Mb)'
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters c
WHERE c.counter_name IN ('Free Memory (KB)', 'Total Server Memory (KB)', 'Target Server Memory (KB)');

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS 'Database', COUNT(*) * 8 / 1024 AS MBUsed
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY database_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) * 8 / 1024 DESC
```

And the results for it are:

```
=========================================
counter_name                Memory (Mb)
=========================================
Free Memory (KB)            5453
Target Server Memory (KB)   28311
Total Server Memory (KB)    24303

=========================================
Database                MBUsed
=========================================
DB1                     7369
DB2                     3924
tempdb                  386
WSS_UsageApplication    244
SharePoint_Config       107
DB3                     95
```

From the first query you can see that I have assigned SQL maximum memory to be used is 28311 Mb and it tells me that the current total usage from the same query is 24303 Mb. But when I run the second query to know more details what is the 24303 Mb being used by the database, then after all the values from the query they do not add to 24303 Mb not even near also.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: The buffer pool isn't the only thing that SQL Server needs memory for. For *one* example, it also has a plan cache.

Comment: how do i which database is what sort of memory overall? All i want to do help me decide on how much to set maximum memory size for sql server

Comment: @KashifKhan, max memory should be set to `physical_memory_available - os_memory_needs - other_application_needs`.  Not sure how breaking usage down by database will help you decide. This question is better suited for dba.stackexchange.com since it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a summary of SQL Server memory by clerk along with total with the query below:

```
SELECT type, SUM(pages_kb)*1024 AS bytes
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY ROLLUP(type);
```

Comment: the above query does not tell me anything which database? I am looking for a query which will help me dissect all kinds of memory used by the SQL server by individual Database.

Comment: Your buffer pool query already breaks buffer cache usage down by database. This is typically the largest memory consumer.  Many of the memory pools are shared among all databases so the memory usage can't easily be categorized by database.